# How to configure Swagger responses for different API versions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

Below is my API for which I have 3 versions:

```
@ApiResponses({
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = SuccessConstants.Message, response = GetInfoResponse.class)})
public ResponseEntity<GetInfoResponse> getInfo(@ApiParam(value = "InfoId", required = true)
{
}

class GetInfoResponse{
    private A a;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private B b;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private C c;
}
```

For v2 API, B object would be null and for v3, C would be null.
Using non null annotation these fields won't be displayed in response JSON for respective versions.

But these fields are displayed in Swagger response models across all versions.
Is there a way in Swagger by which null fields can be hidden?